# RuntimeException propagation from a method called by reflection

Tags: java, reflection, exception

I start right with the code. This one invokes a method using reflection

```
try {
    Method method = states.getClass().getDeclaredMethod(
            getCurrentStateId() + "_" + request.getEvent());
    states.setData(request, dataManager);
    method.invoke(states);
} catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
    logger.debug("Method " + getCurrentStateId() + "_" + request.getEvent()
            + " cannot be found - invocation not performed.", e);
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    throw new InternalException("Method invocation with reflection failed.", e);
} catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
    throw new InternalException("Method invocation with reflection failed.", e);
} catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
    throw new InternalException("Method invocation with reflection failed.", e);
}
```

and calls the method with the following code which throws a `PropertiesDontMatchException` (runtime).

```
...
if (totalCredits < minimumCredits || totalCredits > maximumCredits) {
    throw new PropertiesDontMatchException("Minimum amount of credits=" + minimumCredits
            + ", maximum amount of credits=" + maximumCredits + ". Your amount of credits="                 + totalCredits + ". You have to modify your set of subjects.");
}
...
```

The thing is that my runtime exception is being wrapped into `InvocationTargetException` and caught in the first code snippet. This is not what I want. But according to the documentation, it's the correct behaviour however.

So I came up with this solution

```
...
} catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
    if (e.getCause() instanceof PropertiesDontMatchException) {
        throw (PropertiesDontMatchException) e.getCause();
    }
    throw new InternalException("Method invocation with reflection failed.", e);
}
...
```

Is this the proper way how to propagate my runtime exception or is there any better solution of this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is the correct error handling in this case. I would only extend your test for any `RuntimeException`:

```
} catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
    if (e.getCause() instanceof RuntimeException) {
        throw (RuntimeException) e.getCause();
    }
    if (e.getCause() instanceof Error) {
        throw (Error) e.getCause();
    }
    throw new InternalException("Method invocation with reflection failed.", e);
}
```

Or use [`Throwables` utility class](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Throwables.html) from [guava](/questions/tagged/guava) instead if you don't mind using `RuntimeException` instead of custom `InternalException` for checked exceptions:

```
} catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
    throw Throwables.propagate(e.getCause());
}
```

The extra wrapping is necessary to distinguish between your e.g. your method throwing `IllegalAccessException` and reflection mechanism itself throwing it.

Similar API design choice can be observed with [`Future.get()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get%28long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29) - in case of exception thrown from asynchronous job [`ExecutionException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutionException.html) is thrown wrapping the actual exception.

Comment: I can't do this because I want to wrap other runtime exceptions into InternalException which is then returned to client as a 500 Internal Error. The Properties..Exception is returned as a 400 Bad Request. But thank you for the answer...

Comment: what if `e.getCause() instanceof Error`?

Comment: @Saintali: you are right, I updated my answer and added Guava tip. Thanks!

Comment: Please note that as of 2017, ``Throwables.propagate`` is ``deprecated``.
https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/Why-we-deprecated-Throwables.propagate